# Issue with PHP for saving data

Tags: php, html

my task is to save form data to text file.but,the php isnt getting executed..
even after hitting the submit button, the text file is empty..
please let me know the flaws
myhtml

```
 <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="Input2.php">


 <label>Choose my Map set  :
 </label>
 <select name="Mapset">
  <option value="Global network">Global Network</option>

  </select> <br> 
 <br>

<label>Tiff code:
</label>
<select name="Tiff">
<option value="MX">MX</option>
  </select> <br> <br>
<label>Physical size :
</label>
<input type="text" name="size" size="10"><br>
<label>time:
</label>
<input type="text" name="time" size="10"><br>
<div style="text-align: center"><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Next" class="submit">

<div class="spacer"></div> 
</form>
```

My PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
$data = $_POST['size'];
$data = $_POST['time'];

$file = "input.txt"; 

$fp = fopen($file, "a") or die("Couldn't open $file for writing!");
 fwrite($fp, $data) or die("Couldn't write values to file!"); 

fclose($fp); 
echo "Saved to $file successfully!";
}
header("location:NetOptInput3.html");
```

Comment: Haven't you already asked 2 if not 3 times already on the same subject?

Comment: Where is `$data` defined and populated?

Comment: Plus this will ultimately fail `header("location:NetOptInput3.html");`

Comment: The reason why your code is failing is because of unassigned variables. You have to "tell it" what to save.

Comment: `$info = ''; foreach($_POST as $value) { $info .= $value . "\n"; } file_put_contents('input.txt', $info);`

Comment: Or you can do:  `file_put_contents('input.txt', serialize($_POST));` and than use `unserialize` to grab the array of posted data when reading from it. e.g.:  `$array = unserialize(file_get_contents('input.txt'));`

Comment: this part of my php code didnt get pasted...if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
$data = $_POST['size'];
$data = $_POST['time'];  do you think its still wrong?

Comment: i am  new to php.thats the reason for me to post several of my php code's..thanks for looking into the issue..please let me know the flaws.

Comment: @user2639146 - could you please edit your question, and make sure that the PHP in the question is the same as your actual code?

Comment: @user2639146 The flaws have already been indicated in my comments above. Plus, see my question, it will work for what you wish to accomplish.

Comment: @user2639146 Although after seeing your EDIT, now the "Winds have changed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here give this a try (tested)

You need to assign your `$_POST` values in order to tell it "what" to save in a file.

The way this was done is that it will take all POST values.

You can also assign individual variables like this:

```
$size=$_POST['size'];
```

**Added note:**

You had `header("location:NetOptInput3.html");` and will fail because of a missing space.

This is the proper way `header("Location: NetOptInput3.html");`

**HTML form** (I removed `name="submit"` because that will also show up in the file)

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="Input2.php">
 <label>Choose my Map set  :
 </label>
 <select name="Mapset">
 <option value="Global network">Global Network</option>
 </select> <br> 
 <br>

<label>Tiff code:
</label>
<select name="Tiff">
<option value="MX">MX</option>
 </select> <br> <br>
<label>Physical size :
</label>
<input type="text" name="size" size="10"><br>
<label>time:
</label>
<input type="text" name="time" size="10"><br>
<div style="text-align: center"><br>

<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Next" class="submit">

<div class="spacer"></div> 
</form>
```

**PHP handler** (`Input2.php`)

Note: Using the `a` switch will append/add to the file, while `w` will overwrite all previously saved content.

```
<?php

foreach($_POST as $data) {
$info = '';
$info .= $data . "\n";
$file = "data.txt";
$fp = fopen($file, "a") or die("Couldn't open $file for writing!");

fwrite($fp, $data . "\n") or die("Couldn't write values to file!");
}
fclose($fp); 

// You cannot use both header and echo. Choose one.
// header("Location: NetOptInput3.html");

echo "Success";

?>
```